# About Apex SQL Refactor and SSMS keyboard shortcuts being broken

Tags: sql-server, query-refactor, keyboard-shortcuts

Hi DBA Stack Exchange!

Today I tried Apex SQL Refactor and right from the get go, once installed and integrated into my T-SQL dev tool of Choice (SSMS 18.3.1) I noticed that some Keyboard shortcuts stopped working.

One example (maybe there are more, but this one I’m pretty sure): After installing and using SQL Refactor for first time (Refactor needs to be used at least once for this to happen) the “Available Databases” functionality in SSMS (which can be invoked by CTRL+U) no longer works. What is worse, this is not a configurable shortcut (like most of the Keyboard shortcuts that can be configured on Tools -> Options -> Keyboard) so once it is broken, the only solution so far (to make it work again) is to uninstall SQL Refactor.

This query shortcut (“Available Databases”) is an extremely useful one that people use it over and over again on SQL Sessions, so breaking the shortcut is a major thing for me.

[image]

I’m running the latest available builds of both SSMS (18.3.1) and Apex SQL Refactor (2018.08.0364)

**My question is: have you also experienced this? If so, how did you solve the issue of keyboard shortcuts being irreparably lost after Apex SQL Refactor?**

If you need me to provide any additional info about my system or logs that could help you reproduce this issue, just let me know.

Thanks to all of you!

Comment: Just wanted to stick my head in here and say that while CTRL+U seems to now be working as intended, the CTRL+K, CTRL+U combination for uncommenting selected text in the editor is still broken. It highlights Available Databases as if CTRL+K was not pressed, and CTRL+K is still sitting there waiting for the second combination. Very annoying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just got feedback from the Apex support team.

Apparently this is a known issue and they are working on it. I asked them to contact me so I get notified when a workaround/patch gets released that addresses this problem.